# WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot destructure property

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

When I try `gatsby develop` the application works fine. However, when I try `gatsby build`, I get the following error:

[image]

This is my query (I tested it in GraphQL, and it returns the values correctly)

[image]

I'm using [gatsby-plugin-mdx](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-mdx/).

I don't know what to do. Have someone an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` again? If what you have works in `gatsby develop` but doesn't work with `gatsby build` then perhaps there's a corrupted package or something. Also, you could try `rm -rf public` and `rm -rf .cache` and try `gatsby develop` and `gatsby build` to see if there's any difference.

Comment: I already tried that

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you've provided what the problem is. If you could create a minimal reproducible example and post it to `GitHub` I could take a look.

Comment: The minimal reproducible example is in this [link](https://github.com/ylruiz/gatsby-bug/issues/1). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things that you're missing from your `createPosts` function inside `gatsby-node.js` is the `path` for your blog post so that you can use it in the `GraphQL` query inside `blogTemplate.js`.

Also, it looks like `path` is a reserved property, so you might want to use something else.

```js
// gatsby-node.js

const createPosts = (posts, createPage, blogTempate) => {
  posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
    const path = node.frontmatter.path
    createPage({
      path,
      component: blogTemplate,
      context: {
        blogPath: path,
        ...
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Then, change your query to the following:

```js
// blogTemplate.js

const BlogPost = ({ data }) => {
  // ...
}
export const query = graphql`
  query($blogPath: String) {
    mdx(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $blogPath } }) {
      ...
    }
  }
`
```

Finally, change `gatsby-config.js` so that it looks like the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
    { resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`, ... },
    { resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`, ... }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but I just removed the default property on { resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`, ... } because I have to manage some options with gatsbyRemarkPlugins. Thank you so much.

Comment: @YunetLuisRuíz oh ok, got it, and yeah that `default` property was causing issues. Glad you got it to work.